# Standard Controller - Form - set the record type?

Tags: visualforce

When using apex:form how do you specify a record type? I can tell that it is using the default record type but I want to specify this in the VF page. Do I have to use a custom controller instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom controller logic to achieve this. The controller should fetch the record types for that Object and display as picklist or any other format you may need. Following code is for picklist type:

```
List<RecordType> lstRecTypes = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName from RecordType
                                 WHERE sObjectType = 'Object__c']

List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
for(RecordType redType: lstRecTypes){
    options.add(new selectOption(redType.Id, redType.DeveloperName));
}
```

You could use this option list on your page.